# Let user add a message when selecting shipping method

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

One of our shipping methods let's the customer have their purchase delivered at home. When the user selects that method, we'd like to include a simple textarea where the user can write when he wants his order delivered.

Is there an easy way to go about this? Basically just attach a "user note" to the cart as a whole, not to any individual lineItem

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a text field and add it you field layout for Orders in Commerce settings.

Then in any `updateCart` form you can simply place a value in this by using `<input name="fields[fieldHandle]" etc>`